# What are the difference between "settlement risk" and "counterparty risk"

Tags: risk

From [Lannquist,2020, p.6](https://www.mendeley.com/catalogue/bab1888b-3b36-318e-8d21-153b5f0bd5e5/?utm_source=desktop&utm_medium=1.19.8&utm_campaign=open_catalog&userDocumentId=%7B1ed7fa60-0df9-369d-85c4-5cf5cb034eea%7D), the wholesale Central Bank Digital Currency (CBDC) could reduce **settlement risk** and **counterparty risks**.

I am wondering what is the intuitive difference between these two risks? From Investopedia( [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/settlementrisk.asp), [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/counterpartyrisk.asp)) , these two terms are indistinguishable to me, mostly about default risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investopedia explains the difference clearly:

> What Is Settlement Risk? Settlement risk is the possibility that **one or more parties will fail to deliver on the terms of a contract** at the **agreed-upon time**.

> Default Risk: Default risk is the possibility that **one of the parties fails to deliver on a contract entirely.**

I don't think it can be explained more clearly than that.

Comment: Thanks a heap. And sorry for any inconvenient. I did edit the question. Could you please help me to sort it out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And even as above, the difference between Settlement Risk and Default risk is still not really clear to me. I still cannot separate the settlement risk from default risk. Is there any example to make it more clear? Heaps of thanks

Comment: @Louise I dont understand how you can get even more intuitive here. Ok let me give you example maybe that will help you. SR: you owe me 100 dollars payable 30.12.2021 There is risk that you will not pay on time and pay 100 dollars at 15.1.2022. DR: there is risk I will never see full 100 dollars again you don't pay at all or pay only portion of it

Comment: Ah now I see, thanks a lot @csilvia, thanks for your patience.